# How to parse dynamic id fields in json in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, wikipedia-api

I am trying to extract some info using the wikipedia api - http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&explaintext&exintro=&format=json

The response I get is as below,

```
{"query":
  {"pages":
   {"1350786":
    {"pageid":1350786,"ns":0,"title":"2005 in Wales","extract":"This article is about the particular significance of the year 2005 to Wales and its people."}}}}
```

How can I traverse to the "extract" field here in node.js? I am trying to use query.pages. something but since the id changes for each call I make, I am not sure how to access the extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the id (which is a dictionary key under pages) you can just traverse all the keys under pages to get the extract field:

```
var obj1 =
{
    "query":
    {
        "pages":
        {"1350786":
            {"pageid":1350786,"ns":0,"title":"2005 in Wales",
             "extract":"This article is about the particular significance of the year 2005 to Wales and its people."}
        }
    }
}

for (var key in obj1.query.pages){
    console.log(obj1.query.pages[key].extract);
}
```